# inputstream is closed error while uploading zip file through jsch to sftp site

Tags: inputstream, sftp, jsch

While uploading a zip file to SFTP, we are getting the below error. The same code is working fine for another application. We are using jsch-0.1.44.jar for SFTP connection.

```
java.io.IOException: inputstream is closed
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._put(ChannelSftp.java:571)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:431)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:398)
aused by: java.io.IOException: inputstream is closed
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.fill(ChannelSftp.java:2326)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.header(ChannelSftp.java:2350)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.checkStatus(ChannelSftp.java:1923)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._put(ChannelSftp.java:559)
        ... 6 more
```

Comment: Anyone has any suggestions for this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77352734/how-to-copy-zip-file-from-hdfs-to-sftp-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I searched stackoverflow and many other sources in internet to get an answer.
There were two reasons I found which was not the cause for my specific issue.

1) This exception usually means the connection was closed abruptly. I would look at the logs on the server to see if there was an error.
2)The root cause of this error was that in the code, remote path was being opened twice. So, even if, no channel is actually closed, but, when the remote path is tried to open 2nd time, the existing path/channel is also closed or something and this exception is raised.

After doing some POC, whatever changes we made to code did not have any impact. One of the thing which was looked at was passing inputstream object as a parameter to a method where actually put method of channelsftp is being called.

this.channelSftp.put(inputstream, strFileName );

Instead of passing inputstream from another method, code was written to form inputstream inside the method where this put is being called. This does not have any impact.

Tried uploading a file to sftp site through code. Same error was being thrown.

Later what we found was that there was no code issue. Even a manual upload was failing. This indicated us to dig further about this SFTP engagement details and found that the FILENAME format we are using is not what SFTP has configured. When we matched the filename format, the issue was resolved.

Comment: Which filename format do you use?

Answer (score 2):

I've recently encountered an issue similar to this, in my case it was a an issue when logging on to the remote machine using JSch.

When trying to manually connect to the machine I found that the password had expired and was prompting for a new one on login. It was able to connect and authenticate however once connected it was unable to get any further. This explained why it was an inputstream failure and not an authentication failure.

I know this is an old question but to anyone else in the same position trawling the web for an answer it might just be a simple solution like this.

Comment: Thank. What is the point of hardening a non-production server?

Comment: @ChhornElit company policy unfortunately.

Comment: Anyone has any suggestions for this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77352734/how-to-copy-zip-file-from-hdfs-to-sftp-server

Answer (score 2):

[Nikola](http://stackoverflow.com/users/14345873/nikola-mici%C4%87?tab=profile) and I were facing this issue as well. It was not a problem due to permissions or passwords or whatever.
We are using the CachingSessionFactory. The sessions are closed arbitrarily by the server OR by the client application. We described our solution in another StackOverFlow: [Sftp File Upload Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52886559/sftp-file-upload-fails/66138129#66138129)

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue. Also want to add that it was not related to code but to access rights. I connected with a user that could connect via ssh but that could not send file through stp. Changing the user with proper access rights solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I tried above options, and none seems to be worked for my use case.

In my use case, we upload files to sftp using JSCH parallelly. Most of the uploads were successful but very few used to fail with above error.

On investigating the implementation, I found that the library returns the connection from pool which is not close. In our case one of the thread was closing the connection before another concurrent thread could finish upload hence causing `IOException: input stream is closed error`.

We have enabled `testSession` feature on cachingConnectionFactory. It will return the pooled connection `if it is not closed` and `can actually list files from the SFTP`.  This solved our issue.

Posting the sample code here

```
DefaultSftpSessionFactory sessionFactory1 = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
    sessionFactory1.setHost("host");
    sessionFactory1.setPort(21);
    sessionFactory1.setUser("userName");
    sessionFactory1.setPassword("password");
    CachingSessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> cachingSessionFactory = new CachingSessionFactory<>(sessionFactory, 10);
    cachingSessionFactory.setSessionWaitTimeout(2000);
    cachingSessionFactory.setTestSession(true);`
```