# Sftp File Upload Fails

Tags: java, spring-boot, sftp, jsch, spring-integration-sftp

I have developed a scheduler using spring boot. this scheduler creates text files in a local VM and upload those files into remote FTP location.
scheduler is running at 5 time slots per day. last slot is 11.45 PM.
problem is , at 11.45 P.M the file upload is not working, but files are creating in the local location.
Log is included here

```
2018-10-19 00:00:26.338 ERROR --- [task-scheduler-4] ework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler : org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Error handling message for file [/apps/logs/lesipay-scheduler/to_ctf/ClientCreation18102018_23.txt -> ClientCreation18102018_23.txt]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to write to '/logs/dumpfiles/to_ctf/ClientCreation18102018_23.txt.writing' while uploading the file; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: failed to write file; nested exception is 4: java.io.IOException: inputstream is closed, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=/apps/logs/lesipay-scheduler/to_ctf/ClientCreation18102018_23.txt, headers={id=e914c7a2-2b4c-74e2-92d6-b8158ed72874, timestamp=1539886500712}]
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate$1.doInSession(RemoteFileTemplate.java:321)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate$1.doInSession(RemoteFileTemplate.java:283)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:435)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:283)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:273)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:265)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(FileTransferringMessageHandler.java:170)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
        at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.ServiceActivatorAnnotationPostProcessor$ReplyProducingMessageHandlerWrapper.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatorAnnotationPostProcessor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:143)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:135)
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.send(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:375)
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:477)
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:429)
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:420)
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayCompletableFutureProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayCompletableFutureProxyFactoryBean.java:65)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy72.upload(Unknown Source)
        at lk.dialog.lesipayscheduler.scheduler.LesipayFileGenScheduledTask.writeToSftpFile(LesipayFileGenScheduledTask.java:184)
        at lk.dialog.lesipayscheduler.scheduler.LesipayFileGenScheduledTask.setRepoParams(LesipayFileGenScheduledTask.java:132)
        at lk.dialog.lesipayscheduler.scheduler.LesipayFileGenScheduledTask.fileGeneratorFor21Hr(LesipayFileGenScheduledTask.java:120)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to write to '/logs/dumpfiles/to_ctf/ClientCreation18102018_23.txt.writing' while uploading the file; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: failed to write file; nested exception is 4: java.io.IOException: inputstream is closed
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.sendFileToRemoteDirectory(RemoteFileTemplate.java:558)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.access$500(RemoteFileTemplate.java:60)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate$1.doInSession(RemoteFileTemplate.java:306)
        ... 46 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: failed to write file; nested exception is 4: java.io.IOException: inputstream is closed
        at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.write(SftpSession.java:159)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$CachedSession.write(CachingSessionFactory.java:228)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.sendFileToRemoteDirectory(RemoteFileTemplate.java:530)
        ... 48 more
    Caused by: 4: java.io.IOException: inputstream is closed
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._put(ChannelSftp.java:697)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:540)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:492)
        at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.write(SftpSession.java:156)
        ... 50 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: inputstream is closed
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.fill(ChannelSftp.java:2911)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.header(ChannelSftp.java:2935)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._put(ChannelSftp.java:583)
        ... 53 more
```

code snippet for file uploading

```
private void writeToSftpFile(List<String> stringList, String key, String specialCategory) {
    String outFileName = createSftpDirectory(key,specialCategory);
    if (stringList.size() > 0) {
        try (PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(outFileName)) {
            for (String str : stringList) {
                ps.println(str);
            }
            pathList.add(outFileName);
            logger.info("{} ", outFileName, " created.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Couldn't write file -> {}", e);
        }
    } else {
        logger.info("No record for ->{}", outFileName);
    }

    if (key.equals("facilityKey")) {
        for (String localPath : pathList) {
            logger.info("localpath -> {}", localPath);
            uploadGateway.upload(new File(localPath));
        }
        pathList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    if (specialCategory.equals("facilitySpecial")) {
        for (String localPath : pathList) {
            logger.info("localpath -> {}", localPath);
            uploadGateway.upload(new File(localPath));
        }
        pathList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

}
```

Upload Gateway

```
@Component
@MessagingGateway
public interface UploadGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "toSftpChannel")
    void upload(File file);
}
```

Sftp Configuartion

```
@Configuration
public class SftpConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigSource configSource;

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sftpFileSessionFactory() {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory ssf = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
        ssf.setHost(configSource.getSftpHost());
        ssf.setPort(configSource.getSftpPort());
        ssf.setUser(configSource.getSftpUser());
        ssf.setPassword(configSource.getSftpPassword());
        ssf.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return new CachingSessionFactory<>(ssf);
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toSftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        SftpMessageHandler handler = new SftpMessageHandler(sftpFileSessionFactory());
        handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression(configSource.getRemoteDir()));
        handler.setFileNameGenerator(new FileNameGenerator() {
            @Override
            public String generateFileName(Message<?> message) {
                if (message.getPayload() instanceof File) {
                    return ((File) message.getPayload()).getName();
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("File expected as payload.");
                }
            }
        });
        return handler;
    }
}
```

Comment: look at the [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33405888/inputstream-is-closed-error-while-uploading-zip-file-through-jsch-to-sftp-site)

Comment: @pygo   the problem is this working fine for other time slots.  sometimes this cause because of networking issue ??

Comment: @pygo   do you know how to close the sftp session after file upload is done.

Comment: Why don't you use pysftp ?

Comment: I just posted and way as answer as it could not be posted in comment section, However, there is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432385/sftp-in-python-platform-independent)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

after some monitoring with the network team I could find the root cause for this problem.

the reason is Long opened ssh sessions are being closed arbitrary.  There were no proper mechanism to handle the ssh sessions (after consuming the ssh session close the session).

after handling the session creation and closing we were able to solve the issue

Comment: can you update your code snippets? or link to appropriate documentation for the solution?

Comment: Can you please update the code snippet regarding what all changes you did since I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this:

```
import pysftp as sftp

def sftpExample():
    try:
        s = sftp.Connection('ftp.company.com', username='enterusername', password='enterpassword')

        remotepath1='/home/filepath/sample.xlsx'
        localpath1="\\\\corporatenetwork\\datapath\\sample.xlsx"

        s.get(remotepath1,localpath1, preserve_mtime=True)


        s.close()

    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)

sftpExample()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but  this is for python.  my project is spring boot integration with sftp. do you know any documentation that i can follow

Comment: I'll see if i'll find the one.