# is Channel object of JSch thread safe

Tags: jsch, ssh-tunnel

I want to connect to same host with multiple threads and perform some ssh operations. Can we share the channel object between threads. I tried to use but getting error like java.io.ioexception pipe closed, java.io.IOException: inputstream is closed.
Then on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33405888/inputstream-is-closed-error-while-uploading-zip-file-through-jsch-to-sftp-site) I read that we can't access the different paths of same host with same Channel object. So I suspect that Channel is not thread safe. I am using this [jsch](https://github.com/mwiede/jsch)

Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: yes it cleared for me thanks. we can use it with synchronization block, but better to use one connection for one thread.