# How to copy zip file from hdfs to sftp server

Tags: scala, hadoop, hdfs, sftp

I have a zip file named - "FileName.zip" in hdfs location. I wanted to copy this zip file to sftp server.

The zip folder structure is below (when downloaded to local)-
FileName.zip
- file.txt

If I unzip this onto hdfs the folder structure is different -
FileName.zip
- file.txt
- _SUCCESS
- part-0000000.txt

Here's what I have done so far -
using ChanelSftp object I called the method put(InputStream, destPath)
this throws an error - java.io.FileNotFoundException: /FileName.zip (Is a directory)

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a library? Do you want to access the server from your local machine? From a server where they will be in same network? Do you have to access to the other server throw ssh or some other protocol? Please provide more details about the stack you are using and how thing are organized

Comment: Zip files aren't a file format that's supported by HDFS blocks. Bzip2 files are better since they can be split

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it more complicated than required. You should SSH to the system running the SFTP Server and run `hdfs get` command to download the file.